# Linux distro for Java

Tags: linux, debian, centos, java

I am setting up a server that will run multiple Java programs and requires Java 7.

I am more familiar with Debian but have been advised that CentOS/RHEL has better 64bit Java 7 support.

Is there any noticeable difference in Java performance between different Linux distros?

Would any difference be worth the transition from Debian to CentOS?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Very interesting ekaj thank you. I'll have to have a look. The replies seem to be promoting a stick-with-what-you-know-best answer to my Debian/CentOS decision - I don't expect to see a big difference in performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really no.  Given my druthers, I'll use Centos, and as a RHEL clone, one of the selling points of RHEL is that as a server oriented OS, RHEL has focused on stability and support for esoteric hardware you find in server class machines, which is how Redhat caters to its customer base.

None of that is going to be relevant to a java application server specifically.  In terms of tuning, you want your JVM to have as much memory as it needs for your apps, and you otherwise want as little else running as possible.

Ultimately, you're building an application server devoted to the jvm's you need, so what's more important than your distro, is a firm understanding of the app, via profiling, and tuning the jvm's you're running.  Needless to say, the server needs to be resourced appropriately in terms of memory, so that the machine is never swapping.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience there is no significant difference if any in java performance.

I've been using bot centos and debian/ubuntu with Java7 and usually the main problem with performance is the configuration of the application.

Also keep in mind that tuning GC, ram allocation and some other minor stuff here and there can provide significant boost to performance.

All in all KNOW your application and configure accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The Centos v Debian thing for Java comes from the fact Debian is, by default, very restrictive when it comes to non-free licences and as such the licence Oracle attaches to Java and the fact the package can only be distributes by Oracle ends up being a pain to get natively and out of the box with Debian.

RHEL is a better solution for using the pure-oracle Java stuff, though you may still also have to install directly from Oracle.

Comment: granted yes it is not free sw but tools exist to easily package it in a deb. Ex. the make-jpkg from java-package. It creates a bit ugly package names but works like a charm

Comment: Does that mean I can install a package on debian and expect it to run as well as on CentOS?